# Geometry nodes vs particle system

Tags: modeling, node-editor, particles, geometry, performance

I just want to know the benefits of using geometry nodes over particle systems, such as whether I will be able to generate more particles with less memory usage in geometry nodes.

Why are geometry nodes such a big deal? I didn't find anything interesting in it (or maybe I just don't know how to use it).

Comment: Hello and welcome. Opinion-base questions are not suitable for the site. You could try on another forum like blenderartist. make sure to take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how the site works

Comment: You know GN isn't just for particles, right?  You're just asking about particles though?

Comment: maybe watch some youtube videos what geometry nodes can do. there are lots of them. then you might get an impression. e.g. this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcwWGwyjko8 just watch the first minute and try to do this effect with particles...

Comment: This is a completely valid question with completely non opinion based answer/s.  I have edited it to hopefully make this clearer.   People need to stop closing questions without reading and actually COMPREHENDING.

Answer (score 8):

The big deal with geometry nodes is that we're effectively getting the functionality of geometry shaders now. That's kind of a blunt way of putting it, but if you look that up in the context of GLSL you'll find that they stand between vertex shaders and post processing, and govern full primitives; that is, they can create meshes in the graphics pipeline itself, without having to copy data over for every single instance.

GLSL geometry shaders are largely superseded by compute shaders now, but it's still a common practice to use them for extremely primitive-populated models and the concept is the same. In the past we did indeed use particle systems for this, but a particle is much more simplistic and restricted than geometry nodes, particularly if you aren't trying to work in real-time. They are much more flexible and easier to work procedurally with. (Think Cinema 4D, if you've used it; it's had this advantage for a while now.)

If you attempt to model the same scene with both geometry nodes and particle systems, you'll already notice, as I did, that geometry nodes are substantially easier on your hardware. On top of this, we are opened to node programming for geometry nodes, while particle systems require what I consider to be a much clunkier interface.

Now, if you have something you've already implemented as a particle system, and it works, that's fine; they aren't going anywhere and you shouldn't feel like you have to replace it just yet. Technically they are two different systems that involve instancing; but for geometry nodes it's a core concern whereas with particles it was always more of a tacked-on option.